# Golang: mock struct functions for a test

Tags: go

go version: 1.19x

Here is the function I want to test (statsd is `"github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/v5/statsd"` external lib)

```
s, err := statsd.New(StatsdHost)

emitGauge(s, 10.0)

// need to test below function
func emitGauge(s *statsd.Client, i float64) {

    // calls statsd Gauge function
    // s.Gauge("name", i, "", 1)

}
```

I want my test to pass in a mock object for `statsd.Client` and assert that correct values were passed in to `s.Gauge`

I've tried

```
type StubStatsd struct{}

func (s StubStatsd) Gauge(name string, value float64, tags []string, rate float64) error {
    return nil
}
```

but I'm getting `Cannot use 'statsdStub' (type StubStatsd) as the type *statsd.Client`

What's the right way to test this type of function?

Comment: You can't mock `*statsd.Client`. Your question has been answered a million times here on SO. Please use the search bar.

Comment: Your function `emitGauge` needs to take an interface. If it takes a concrete type, that is the only type you can pass it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change your function to accept an interface.

```
type Gauger interface {
    Gauge(name string, value float64, tags []string, rate float64) error
}

func emitGauge(s Gauger, i float64) {
    s.Gauge("name", i, "", 1)
}
```

and then you can do what you had for the mock

```
type StubStatsd struct{}

func (s StubStatsd) Gauge(name string, value float64, tags []string, rate float64) error {
    return nil
}
```